# Reducible polynomials of the shape $f(t^2)$, where $f$ is irreducible

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic, irreducible polynomial. What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $g(t) = f(t^2)$ to be reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

For instance, if $f(x) = x-1$ then $g(x) = x^2 - 1$ is reducible. A less obvious example is $f(x) = x^2 + 4$, then $g(t) = f(t^2) = t^4 + 4 = (t^2 + 2t + 2)(t^2 - 2t + 2)$ is reducible. This latter example can be explained by noting that

$$\displaystyle f(x) = (x + 2i)(x - 2i) = (\sqrt{x} + 1 + i)(\sqrt{x} + 1 - i)(\sqrt{x} -1 + i)(\sqrt{x} - 1 - i).$$

In particular, I am interested in the case when $\deg f \geq 3$.

Comment: Just an example to illustrate that there are lots of $f$ of the type you're looking for: $f(x)=x^6-291x^5+307x^4-110x^3+283x^2+373x+121$ is irreducible, but $f(x^2)=(x^6-x^4+17x^2+11)^2-(17x^5-8x^3+x)^2$ (this was how I found $f$: as the difference of the square of an even polynomial and the square of an odd polynomial; this was the first one that I tried. Note that a necessary condition is that the constant term is a square.

Comment: If $f(t^2) = h(t) k(t)$ for non-trivial monic $h,k$ then each pair $\alpha, -\alpha$ of roots of $f(t^2)$ has to be split between the two factors $h,k$, since if say $h$ claimed both $\alpha,-\alpha$ as roots then the GCD of $h(t)$ and $h(-t)$ would eventually give you a non-trivial factor of $f$.  So we in fact have $k(t) = h(-t)$ and so the question is when there is a factorisation of the form $f(t^2) = h(t) h(-t)$.  Not sure if one can simplify this condition much further.

Comment: ... well, okay, following Anthony's suggestion of splitting $h$ into even and odd parts an equivalent form is $f(t) = \pm ( p(t)^2 - t q(t)^2 )$ for some polynomials $p,q$ with rational coefficients of degree at most $\mathrm{deg} f/2$ and $(\mathrm{deg} f-1)/2$ respectively (the sign $\pm$ depends on whether $\mathrm{deg} f$ is even or odd).

Comment: A reformulation is that a root $\alpha$ of $f$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. This also allows to produce many examples: Start with any irreducible $g$ of odd degree, let $\beta$ be a root of $g$ and let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$.

Comment: A remark is that you are asking for a characterization of the split primes for the Dedekind extension obtained by adjoining a square root of $x$ to $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: This is related to the Graeffe transform, sending a polynomial $P(x)$ to the polynomial $Q(x)$ defined by $P(x)P(-x)=Q(x^2)$, see Rodriguez Villegas, Experimental number theory, 7.1.2. So the question is what polynomials are Graeffe transforms. The Graeffe transform can be computed very quickly, but I don't know in the other direction.

Comment: Some time ago it was a contest problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c78466_2014_imar_test

Comment: Graeffe's method is also used in Hensel lifting in finite fields and rings. For example, in coding theory and sequence design (via trace maps) the Galois Ring $GR(p^2,m)$ plays a part, usually $p=2$ is of most practical interest. The finite field $GF(2^m)$ is essentially $GF(2)[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $m.$ Using Graeffe's method one can find a polynomial (let $p=2$ for concreteness) $q(x)$ of degree $m$ termed a basic irreducible polynomial whose modulo 2 reduction is the polynomial $p(x)$. The Galois ring $GR(p^2,m)=GR(2^2,m)$ is then  $Z_4[x]/(q(x))$.